# bound on compound poisson process

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

I am trying to find a "good" bound for $P(C_t \geq a)$, where $C_t$ is the compound poisson process, i.e.
$$
C_t = \sum^{N_t}_{i=1} Y_i.
$$
$(N_t)_t$ is a homogeneous Poisson process with rate $\lambda$ and $(Y_n)_n$ are iid random variables which are independent of $(N_t)_t$.
I tried to use Markov with $h(x) = e^{sx}$: 
$$
P(C_t \geq a) \leq \frac{\mathbb{E}(e^{sC_t})}{e^{sa}} = \exp((M_{Y_1}(s) - 1)\lambda t - sa),
$$
where $M_{Y_1}(s)$ is the moment-generating function. 
I tried to find $s$ by differentiating and got $\frac{d}{ds} M_{Y_1}(s) - a = 0$.
But now I don't know how to continue, can anyone help? 
Is the idea (to use Markov with $h(x) = e^{sx}$) good or is there another way?

Thanking you in advance! 
Thomas

Comment: Is $E(Y)\lt a/(\lambda t)$?

Comment: Since $E(C_t) = \lambda t E(Y)$ we have that: $E(Y) = E(C_t)/(\lambda t)$. Hence $E(Y) < a/(\lambda t)$ iff $E(C_t) < a$.

Comment: This was not my question. The point is that if $x<\lambda E(Y)$ then the event $C_t\gt xt$ has nonvanishing probability when $t\to\infty$.